# External Hard Drives Not Detected

Tags: 11.10, mount, external-hdd

I am a novice user who upgraded to 11.10. In my previous version of Ubuntu, icons of my external drives(2) were visible and I could mount and navigate these drives. I cannot locate  my external hard drives with 11.10. I have searched the questions with similar titles and have not found a solution.

The command: `sudo fdisk -l` does list both external hard drives. How do I get icons of these drives to appear in my Home Folder? i want to be able to navigate my external hard drive files by clicking on the icons and not using the terminal for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found for my problem:

Apparently the ntfs-3g driver used in linux to read and write NTFS partitions was not installed. Please see ubuntu documentation: "Mounting Windows Partitions". After installing the "ntfs-config" package my problem was solved.

Per the ubuntu documentation: "The ntfs-3g packages comes pre-installed in currently supported versions of Ubuntu and most NTFS devices should work out of the box without further configuration (this may not come packaged with 11.10 - Oneiric Ocelot so be sure to check your system if you run into problems with mounting NTFS filesystems after an install or upgrade)."